# Target element only if it doesn't have any subsequent siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup and style:

```css
[class^="container"] .target:last-of-type {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="target">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="target">5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to select the `.target` element, but only if it is the last within its container.

The `:last-of-type` class works in this case, I just don't understand why. Shouldn't it highlight both `.target` elements? They are the last-of-type (and only) elements within their parent containers. Or I am misunderstanding the `:last-of-type` selector?

Comment: _“The :last-of-type class works in this case, I just don't understand why”_ – because the element is the last of its type (div) in the parent, and happens to have the class `target` as well.

Comment: Same problem as [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2717480/1529630), but for the last element instead of first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:last-of-type` doesn't look for the class, but rather, as the name implies, the `type` as in the `tag` of the element.

That's why it's only highlighting the last element on the second container div, it's applying the rule when the `.target` becomes also the `:last-of-type`, that is, the last `div` inside its container.

I've edited your answer, check what it does when it's either `.item` or the `div` tag itself before the `last-of-type` selector.

```css
[class^="container"] .target:last-of-type {
  color:blue;
}
[class^="container"] .item:last-of-type {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

[class^="container"] div:last-of-type {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="target">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="target">5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, like most things, but is so hard to see if you're looking the wrong way! [x-y problem I guess.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: So basically it was selecting all of the children elements (based on tag names, not classes) and then matched them with a single class selector. It is clear now. Thanks!